# Poor MMIO performance with non-temporal loads on Intel Xeon

Tags: performance, x86, avx, pci, memory-mapped-io

I'm seeing poor memory (WC) read performance with the `vmovntdqa` non-temporal load
instruction on Intel Xeon E-2224 systems, but excellent performance on AMD
EPYC 3151 systems. Why such a huge difference, and is there anything I could do
about it? It seems like the instruction is not working at all as expected on
the Intel systems.

I have DDR memory on an FPGA board attached to PCI Express. I'm using `mmap()`
from user space to access the PCI BAR to which said DDR memory is mapped.
The BAR is marked prefetchable, and as expected, Linux provides the `_wc`
resource files under sysfs accordingly.

Here are my benchmark results:

```
System: Dell R240
CPU: Intel Xeon E-2224
Read speed (memcpy()): 13.7 MB/s
Read speed (streaming/NT load): 9.6 MB/s

System: Supermicro M11SDV-4C-LN4F
CPU: AMD EPYC 3151
Read speed (memcpy()): 6.8 MB/s
Read speed (streaming/NT load): 273.6 MB/s
```

The poor performance also happens on Dell R250 (Intel Xeon E-2314) and
SuperMicro X11SCA-F (Intel Xeon E-2224G).

The benchmark program (C++, Linux) was:

```cpp
/* iobench.cpp */

#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <chrono>
#include <cassert>
#include <cstring>
#include <iostream>

/* streaming-load-memcpy.cpp (adapted from Mesa, see below) */
void util_streaming_load_memcpy(void* __restrict__ dst,
                                void* __restrict__ src,
                                size_t len);

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    const size_t sz = 4 * 1024 * 1024; /* 4 MB */
    assert(argc == 2);

    int sysfs_fd = open(argv[1], O_RDWR | O_CLOEXEC);
    if (sysfs_fd == -1) assert_perror(errno);

    void* src = mmap(nullptr, sz, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, sysfs_fd, 0);

    if (src == (void*)-1) assert_perror(errno);
    if (close(sysfs_fd) == -1) assert_perror(errno);

    char* dst = static_cast<char*>(aligned_alloc(4096, sz));
    assert(dst != nullptr);

    std::chrono::steady_clock::time_point begin;
    std::chrono::steady_clock::time_point end;

    begin = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
    util_streaming_load_memcpy(dst, src, sz);
    // Or: memcpy(dst, src, sz); */
    end = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();

    float duration_sec = std::chrono::duration<float>(end - begin).count();
    float speed = sz / duration_sec / 1024.0 / 1024.0;
    std::cout << speed << " MB/s\n";

    if (munmap(src, sz) == -1) assert_perror(errno);
}
```

`util_streaming_load_memcpy()` was adapted from
the [Mesa project](https://github.com/Mesa3D/mesa/blob/e4e4ba2/src/util/streaming-load-memcpy.c) (minor changes are needed to make it compile standalone).

- Compile: `g++ -mavx -O2 iobench.cpp streaming-load-memcpy.cpp -o iobench`
- Run like: `./iobench /sys/bus/pci/devices/0000\:13\:00.0/resource2_wc`

The streaming load loop of `util_streaming_load_memcpy()` compiled to:

```
...
1540:       c4 e2 79 2a 1e          vmovntdqa (%rsi),%xmm3
1545:       c4 e2 79 2a 56 10       vmovntdqa 0x10(%rsi),%xmm2
154b:       48 83 c6 40             add    $0x40,%rsi
154f:       48 83 c0 40             add    $0x40,%rax
1553:       c4 e2 79 2a 4e e0       vmovntdqa -0x20(%rsi),%xmm1
1559:       c4 e2 79 2a 46 f0       vmovntdqa -0x10(%rsi),%xmm0
155f:       c5 f9 7f 58 c0          vmovdqa %xmm3,-0x40(%rax)
1564:       c5 f9 7f 50 d0          vmovdqa %xmm2,-0x30(%rax)
1569:       c5 f9 7f 48 e0          vmovdqa %xmm1,-0x20(%rax)
156e:       c5 f9 7f 40 f0          vmovdqa %xmm0,-0x10(%rax)
1573:       48 39 d6                cmp    %rdx,%rsi
1576:       75 c8                   jne    1540 <_Z26util_streaming_load_memcpyPvS_m+0x40>
...
```

I have tried the following, but nothing seems to make any meaningful difference:

- Tweak UEFI BIOS settings
- Run a recent stable kernel (6.2.6)
- Disable speculative execution mitigations (kernel cmdline `mitigations=off`)
- Update Intel microcode (tests done with microcode 0xf0)
- Use 256-bit NT loads (`vmovntdqa` with `ymm*` registers)
- Check `/sys/kernel/debug/x86/pat_memtype_list`; the memory is listed as `write-combining`
- Use Dell R240 on-board Matrox G200eW3 GPU memory for reading instead of
  our FPGA DDR

Since there have been numerous CPU vulnerabilities, including "MMIO Stale Data
Vulnerabilities", I can't help thinking, is this a result of some mitigations in
either the CPU microcode or design? The microcode cannot be downgraded easily
below the version loaded by the firmware.

Comment: Could it be the old issue of PCIe through chipset vs direct? So, a motherboard issue rather than CPU.

Comment: @SimonGoater I checked, but at least on the affected SuperMicro X11SCA-F, it was directly to CPU. Dell documentation is not very explicit on this topic.